# How to test login page with multiple webpage(present in notepad) using selenium web driver Java?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am testing like 100 url everything is working good. my problem is when the test starts it get web url from notepad then open the url here my process is to check the login or not in some case if the for example 10th url shows 404 error the test terminate here it cant process further urls. Any solution for this process...

my codes

```
public class File {
@Test(dataProvider="testdata")
public void sum(String url)
{
    System.out.println(url);
}
@DataProvider
public Object[][] testdata(){
int count=20;
Object[][] obj = new Object[count][1];
for(int i=0;i<=count;i++)
{
String fileName = "E:\\ework\\Web\\bin\\Websearch\\test.txt";
try {
String line = null;
FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(fileName);
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);

while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
{
    String[] abs={line};
    int size = abs.length;
    for(int j=0;j<=size;j++)
    {
    obj[i][0]=abs[j];    
    }
}   
bufferedReader.close();
} 
 catch(FileNotFoundException ex) {
     System.out.println(
         "Unable to open file '" + 
         fileName + "'");                
 }
 catch(IOException ex) {
     System.out.println(
         "Error reading file '" 
         + fileName + "'");    
}
```

`}

```
return obj;
```

}
}

thank you.:)

Comment: Part of the code seems missing, please check it and, in case post the whole code.

Comment: Now I am changes my program but still it's not working 1test only pass got some error in console like outofbound exception any solution to get input from notepad given in dataprovider testing Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

1. If you are using framework like TestNG then look at DataProviders for the same.
2. Use `Try{} Catch(Exception e){}` block. Insert your assertion in try block and once the assertion fails then try to capture the exception in some list or other data structure and after all urls are processed then iterate over the exception list and report it in your Reports or logs.

Comment: Now I am changes my program but still it's not working 1test only pass got some error in console like outofbound exception any solution to get input from notepad given in dataprovider testing Thank you :)

Comment: hey outofbounds exception occurs when there is some problem in looping..pls chk the loop in debug mode..you must be iterating more than the elements in the DS